# Nodejs server not available in the LAN

Tags: node.js

allowing LAN access to server does not work.
I've read that this should work: `.listen(1337);`

instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 I can now acces the server with lanip:1337
However, other systems on my lan can't connect to it: http://lanip:1337

tried `.listen(1337, "0.0.0.0");`
did not work as well.

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: Yes I have. Thanks Aleksandr, it was the first thing I thought of. I just turned off my firewall but with no succes

Answer (score 0):

-_- router settings were blocking it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i was answering my own question in case people were having the same issue